# Dockerize React native project and run in emulator

Tags: android, react-native, docker, android-emulator

I thought to dockerize my react native project so that anyone in the team do not need to setup the build environment. I have written the docker file something like

```
FROM reactnativecommunity/react-native-android

LABEL version="0.0.1"

ENV ADB_IP="10.0.2.15"
ENV REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOST="172.17.0.2"

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 19000
EXPOSE 19001

RUN adb connect ${ADB_IP}

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But when I see logs it is unable to find the emulator running in host machine and hence breaking in the end. I have mentioned Emulator and container IP while running the container something like:

```
docker build -t rn-android .
docker run -e ADB_IP=10.0.2.15 \
            -e REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=172.17.0.2 \
            -p 19000:19000 \
            -p 19001:19001 \
            rn-android
```

Comment: Did you get more information about this?

Comment: No didn't find any solution

Comment: @LautaroZarandon, were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem nope